# Cropping out a portion of a string and printing using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to crop a portion of a list of strings and print them. The data looks like the following -

```
Books are on the table\nPick them up
Pens are in the bag\nBring them
Cats are roaming around
Dogs are sitting
Pencils, erasers, ruler cannot be found\nSearch them
Laptops, headphones are lost\nSearch for them
```

(This is just few lines from 100 lines of data in the file)

I have to crop the string before the \n in line 1,2,5,6 and print them. I have to also print line 3,4 along with them. Expected output -

```
Books are on the table
Pens are in the bag
Cats are roaming around
Dogs are sitting
Pencils erasers ruler cannot be found
Laptops headphones are lost
```

What I have tried so far -

First I replace the `comma` with a `space` - `a = name.replace(',',' ');`

Then I use regex to crop out the substring. My regex expression is - `b = r'.*-\s([\w\s]+)\\n'`. I am unable to print line 3 and 4 in which `\n` is not present.

The output that I am receiving now is -

```
Books are on the table
Pens are in the bag
Pencils erasers ruler cannot be found
Laptops headphones are lost
```

What should I add to my expression to print out lines 3 and 4 as well?

TIA

Comment: Try [`re.sub(r'\\n.*|[^\w\s]+', '', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/LifXkR/1)

Comment: I get the following error - `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'groups'` (Updated my code in the post)

Comment: There can't be any groups, it is a `re.sub`, it removes the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and *remove* the line parts starting with a combination of a backslash and `n`, or all punctuation (non-word and non-whitespace) chars using a [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
a = re.sub(r'\\n.*|[^\w\s]+', '', a)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LifXkR/1)

**Details**

- `\\n.*` - a `\`, `n`, and then the rest of the line
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]+` - 1 or more chars other than word and whitespace chars

If you need to make sure there is an uppercase letter after `\n`, you may add `[A-Z]` after `n` in the pattern.

Comment: I have a small additional query with which I am struggling with. If the data looked like `V0.00 - Books are on the table\nPick them up` and each digit in `V0.00` range from 0-3. What modifications do I need to make to get the output `Books are on the table`? I was trying to search for `-` and remove the string before that. But it's not working

Comment: Not sure I get this requirement. If you mean all text from the start of the line up to the first space-hyphen-space should be removed, use [`(?m)^.*? - |\\n.*|[^\w\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/LifXkR/2)

Answer (score 0):

I know many people like to twist their minds into knots with regex but why not,

```
with open('geek_lines.txt') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        print (line.rstrip().split(r'\n')[0])
```

Simple to write, simple to read, seems to produce the correct result.

```
Books are on the table
Pens are in the bag
Cats are roaming around
Dogs are sitting
Pencils, erasers, ruler cannot be found
Laptops, headphones are lost
```